# Why Sanitize Web user input If modern frameworks (Angular, React etc.) handle XSS attacks automatically

Tags: user-input, xss

What is considered to be 'best practices' when it comes to XSS mitigation? Recently, I had a discussion with a Web Developer who claimed that sanitizing user input data that came from an Angular Framework based application (and is also only consumed by said application) is a waste of time and that the user entered data, XSS and all, should just be stored in the database without any form of sanitation. He claimed that these 'Stored XSS Attacks' are not really attacks at all, since the Server/Database does not care about them and they can have Zero effect on the database or business logic, therefore putting a bunch of sanitize logic in the REST API that supplies the Angular application with data is a waste of time and considered to be an 'old school' way of thinking that has been surpassed with the use of modern frameworks. Further, he feels that the 'responsibility' of XSS is purely the problem of the browser, since it is the only thing that is susceptible to the XSS in the first place. Therefore, we should remove all sanitize checks in the REST API, as they are basically pointless.

We use the Angular framework, but we also perform field level sanitation in some but not all cases in the REST API used by the Angular application, and we are considering expending the considerable effort on sanitizing the remaining user entered fields.